# Android TextureView OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I have two fragments that has a TextureView to show camera preview or to play video.

after using the app for a while, playing with the screens, 
i get this error in the logcat

```
OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

i release everything from my fragments,
all members are set to null.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Logg.DEBUG(TAG, "onDestroyView");
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }

    nextButton = null;
    pauseButton = null;
    backButton = null;
    playButton = null;
    frontTextView = null;
    backTextView = null;
    surface = null;
    videoView = null;
}
```

and i see the whole view become weird...

what am i missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in any device? or emulator?

Comment: Devices.
Nexus 5, Galaxy S3/4, Moto G etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows situation when system OpenGL context is corrupted / broken. Please check on what thread you release your resouces. GLContext should be destroyed from exactly same thread where it was allocated. In your case it could be setSurface/setDisplay calls made from wrong thread.

If you have stable and easy steps to reproduce you can try to capture GL log using [Tracer for OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html), but its slows your application **a lot** during capturing