# Android webview performance issue (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, opengl-es, chromium

I'm using webview for my android app. HTML5 is loaded from assets, but logcat keeps throwing these errors:

> E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(1953)] [.WebGLRenderingContext-0xaed91630]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoWillUseTexImageIfNeeded: <- error from previous GL command

and

> E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_manager.cc(1701)] [.WebGLRenderingContext-0xaef86470]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexImage2D: <- error from previous GL command

It doesn't crash the app but performance drops dramatically.
I've found answer to similar issue, but can't figure out where exactly is the problem: [Android TextureView OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280385/android-textureview-openglrenderer-gl-invalid-operation)

My code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Thanks

Comment: did u read this? http://www.felixjones.co.uk/neo%20website/Android_View/

Comment: Turns out the GL errors weren't the cause of performance issues. After orientation change the webview relouded html5 and shortly after performance dropped. Since the activity only has webview in layout, I solved this by adding `@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){ super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);}` and `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` ... Of course this isn't the solution for GL errors.